# How to access data from FileCloud database?

Tags: python, storage

I have a project which need to access all the data from Filecloud.

I have try using API but none of those are suitable. There is a solution to download all the data but it too large for me to download all these. Is there any solution just to read the data via API or some platform available right now.

Comment: Based on [FileCloud documentation](https://fcapi.filecloud.com), could you use [dosearch](https://fcapi.filecloud.com/#/file/dosearch) to search for a specify and then use the search id to download the result with [downloadsearchresults](https://fcapi.filecloud.com/#/file/downloadsearchresults) API?